# The relationship among models

Tags: django, database

I would like to design a simple app where each user will do the same survey of 30 questions, for each of the question, he or she will choose Yes or No.

As I know there are 3 kinds of relationship : One-To-One, Many-To-One, Many-To-Many.

However, I don't know which way is the most optimal to set the relationships.

Here is what I think :

```
User:
+ id (PK)
+ name

Question:
+ id (PK)
+ content

Choice:
+ user (Foreign Key) //Many-To-One or One-To-One ? (1) 
+ question (Foreign Key) //Many-To-One or One-To-One ? (2)
```

I got stuck here because I am not sure if :

(1) 
1 User can make many choices (Many-To-One) OR 1 User can make ONLY 1 choice for each Question (One-To-One)  ?

(2)
1 Question has only 1 Choice(Yes/No) OR 1 Question can be "Yes" for this User and "No" for another User.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship between User and Choice is a simple one-to-many, because one user can have many choices for many questions.

For the same reason, so is the relationship between User and Question.

Additionally, what might be buffling is the fact that there should be a `unique_together` constraint for both user and question fields of the Choice model, as there should be only one choice per user per question.

More on [model meta options and unique together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/options/#unique-together).

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Please forgive me if my next question is too ignorant: As I understand your answer, User and Question are in One-To-Many relationship because 1 User has many Question objects. However, I wonder if there is a way to just create 30 objects of Questions and reused them across many User. If this is possible, so 1 Question can be used by many Users. In this case, the relationship between User and Question would be Many-To-Many?

In addition, what is the relationship between Choice and Question?

Comment: You are too confused about this and I don't know how to make it clearer to you. There is always a matter of opinion when it comes to data modeling, but to me it appears that Question and User have absolutely no relationship apart from the Choice model, which shows which choice a User has made regarding a Question. Having said that, there are many ways that you can model this and it comes down to many factors such as the queries that you will use etc. For instance, you could use a many-to-many relationship with Choice being the through model. If you should, nobody can tell in this context.

Comment: Thank you Wtower! I will read more from model meta options you gave me and try out you suggestion! Nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements is as follows:

1. There are 30 questions for many user to choose.
2. For one questions,user has two choice, yes or no.

so

```
from django.db import models
class Choice(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice = models.BooleanField()
```

Comment: Thank you Bill.He! Nice day!